# Where do i get the Stripe.API key?

Tags: java

Right now I want to develop a payment service, my problem is I didn't understand that part with the Stripe.apikey.

Do I have to generate this apikey? Or is this generated by Stripes? If yes how do I fetch this apiKey from the DB because I want to couple/save it with charge process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Straight from Stripe's docs:

> **Where do I find my API keys?**
>
> Your API keys are located in your [account settings](https://dashboard.stripe.com/account/apikeys).
>
> If you do not see your [API keys](https://dashboard.stripe.com/account/apikeys), this means that you have either Read
>   & Write or Read Only access, and are not an administrator for the
>   account.
>
> You will need to get in touch with the administrator of your account
>   for the API keys or to request that they make you an administrator in
>   the account's [team settings](https://dashboard.stripe.com/account/team).

[Source](https://support.stripe.com/questions/where-do-i-find-my-api-keys)

Comment: okay thanks for your interest on this topic, I guess I'll understood something wrong here, I try to develop a "payment gateway" to Stripe, which would be my payment provider, I thought every User on my page would be later having an API key, in other words, is this API key just for me as developer ? Because if not I want to save that from every User by using set() and get() methodes and using them in my charge process

Comment: Correct, the API keys are associated with your Stripe account.